# german to english float system in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, for-loop

When I try to run a for loop in my bash script with an incrementation of 0.5. The script gives the output in the German floating system. 
eg:

```
for i in $(seq 2.0 0.5 4.0)
do
echo $i
done
```

The output it gives is :

```
2,0
2,5
3,0
3,5
4,0
```

I need to fix this because most of my files are named according to these numbers. With this error, my script is unable to read such files. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use `echo ${i/,/.}`

Comment: `LANG=en_US; for i in $(seq 2.0 0.5 4.0); do LANG=en_US.UTF-8 echo "$i"; done` should work

Comment: thanks thats something new I learnt.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caused by your locale settings, specifically `LC_NUMERIC`.

On my system, where I don't see the symptom you describe:

```
$ locale | grep LC_NUMERIC
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
```

I don't know what locales you have installed on your system. Presumably your default locale uses commas for decimals. The `"C"` locale uses `.`.

Changing

```
seq 2.0 0.5 4.0
```

to

```
LC_NUMERIC=C seq 2.0 0.5 4.0
```

should do the trick.

If you want to use `.` rather than `,` in general, you might consider setting `$LC_NUMERIC` in your shell startup file (`.bashrc`, or `.bash_profile`, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${i/,/.}" # Recommend double quoting the variables.
```

would do the trick. What we have done here is shell [[ parameter expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).